# Applying Pandas iterrows logic across many groups in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, pandas-groupby

I am having trouble applying some logic across my entire dataset. I am able to apply the logic on a small "group" but not on all of the groups (note, the groups are made by `primaryFilter` and `secondaryFilter`. Do you all mind pointing me in the right direction to go about this?

#### Entire Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myInput = {
    'primaryFilter': [100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,100,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200],
    'secondaryFilter': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
    'constantValuePerGroup': [15,15,15,15,20,20,20,17,17,17,10,10,30,30,30,30,22,22,22,22], 
    'someValue':[3,1,4,7,9,9,2,7,3,7,6,4,7,10,10,3,4,6,7,5]
          }
df_input = pd.DataFrame(data=myInput)
df_input
```

[image]

#### Test Data (First Group)

```
df_test = df_input[df_input.primaryFilter.isin([100])]
df_test = df_test[df_test.secondaryFilter == 1.0]

df_test['newColumn'] = np.nan

for index,row in df_test.iterrows():

    if index==0:
        print("start")
        df_test.loc[0, 'newColumn'] = 0

    elif index==df_test.shape[0]-1:
        df_test.loc[index, 'newColumn'] = df_test.loc[index-1, 'newColumn'] + df_test.loc[index-1, 'someValue']
        print("end")

    else:
        print("inter")
        df_test.loc[index, 'newColumn'] = df_test.loc[index-1, 'newColumn'] + df_test.loc[index-1, 'someValue']

df_test["delta"] = df_test["constantValuePerGroup"] - df_test['newColumn']
df_test.head()
```

#### Here is the output of the test

[image]

## I now would like to apply the above logic to the remaining groups `100,2` and `100,3` and `200,1` and so forth..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `iterrows` here, you can `group` the dataframe on `primaryFilter` and `secondaryFilter` columns then for each unique group take the cumulative sum of values in column `someValue` and `shift` the resulting cummulative sum by `1` position downwards to obtain  `newColumn`. Finally subtract `newColumn` from `constantValuePerGroup` to get the `delta`.

```
df_input['newColumn'] = df_input.groupby(['primaryFilter', 'secondaryFilter'])['someValue'].apply(lambda s: s.cumsum().shift(fill_value=0))
df_input['delta'] = df_input['constantValuePerGroup'] - df_input['newColumn']
```

---

```
>>> df_input

    primaryFilter  secondaryFilter  constantValuePerGroup  someValue  newColumn  delta
0             100                1                     15          3          0     15
1             100                1                     15          1          3     12
2             100                1                     15          4          4     11
3             100                1                     15          7          8      7
4             100                2                     20          9          0     20
5             100                2                     20          9          9     11
6             100                2                     20          2         18      2
7             100                3                     17          7          0     17
8             100                3                     17          3          7     10
9             100                3                     17          7         10      7
10            200                1                     10          6          0     10
11            200                1                     10          4          6      4
12            200                2                     30          7          0     30
13            200                2                     30         10          7     23
14            200                2                     30         10         17     13
15            200                2                     30          3         27      3
16            200                3                     22          4          0     22
17            200                3                     22          6          4     18
18            200                3                     22          7         10     12
19            200                3                     22          5         17      5
```